# Website returns 403 even after adding FULL headers

Tags: python, python-requests, get, http-headers, http-status-code-403

I am trying to scrape this website https://m.happymh.com/manga/woshidashenxian
I opened the website went to network tab and copied all request headers but still It returns
<Response [403]>
this is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests

headers = {
'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
'cookie': 'cf_chl_2=f373e3404fcfe3d; cf_chl_prog=x15; cf_clearance=YWgQgOdhpIFKidcylThBHucmFTo9fZUeMbx.NaNcdPo-1662119263-0-150; googtrans=/auto/en; googtrans=/auto/en; __cf_bm=T2khXlk4q8BMAzMjb8AbWxl_OICR_eX4FpGiVHVCcIQ-1662121428-0-ARhjiVlo0ciLOELOiTPG0mX9WSZEXkU8vAElAWYPcLe9i8MD+VQMjHKEIkIOC2llsn54DjFQDyOnv5PuRI1xY1seb3492yPZuonVJK1B4XJ9KdLGoZ/qgNUqPVAQ8NNXOSlBx7v+trtgDP3uByd4n8FUoonx2sBtq6GSTpdYHs9k',
'if-modified-since': 'Fri, 02 Sep 2022 06:39:35 GMT',
'referer': 'https://search.brave.com/',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
'sec-gpc': '1',
'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36'
}

link = 'https://m.happymh.com/manga/woshidashenxian'

req = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
print(req)
```

this is my network tab

[not enough repetitions click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er8Db.png)

Comment: the request that receives the page is of type **Post**,  too much data needs to be substituted in the request, so I don’t think you can bypass the protection of this site, so use selenium

Comment: can you show me the post data that is getting sent?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9uCC.png